# Common Lisp Macros Without Parantheses and Unusual Call Syntax

Tags: macros, common-lisp

I am wondering how one writes macros in Common Lisp that allow him to part with Lisp forms in calls to the former.

For instance, suppose I have the following macro:

```
(defmacro define-route ((app uri method) &body body)
  `(setf (ningle:route ,app ,uri :method ,method)
     ,@body))
```

A call to it would look something like this:

```
(define-route (*app* "/" :GET)
       (print "Welcome to ningle using GET!"))
```

What if one wanted to write a macro that could be called like this:

```
@route(*app*, "/", :GET)
```

or like this:

```
route: *app*, "/", :GET
```

Is this possible? I have seen the `@route` syntax somewhere before but am not sure how to implement it, nor do I remember what it was called to look it up again.

Comment: Lisp macros can't do that. But if you want to develop a new programming language syntax, you can write a parser for it. If you want to do basic extensions to s-expressions, then google for 'reader macros'.

Answer (score 2):

We encounter this *decorator* syntax (or *annotations* in CL) in the [Caveman](https://github.com/fukamachi/caveman) or [Lucerne](https://github.com/eudoxia0/lucerne) web frameworks:

```
@route GET "/"
(defun index ()
  (render #P"index.tmpl"))
```

I doubt you can do `route: *app*, "/", :GET`.

[cl-annot](https://github.com/m2ym/cl-annot) is a general annotation library for CL.

It is a reader macro, more examples here: http://lisp-lang.org/wiki/article/reader-macros

ps: [Snooze](https://github.com/joaotavora/snooze), by the author of Sly (and yasnippet), is a web frameworks that treats routes as usual functions, thus route parameters as usual function arguments. It also has built-in reporting of errors (in browser, in the debugger, with a custom 404 page). I liked it better than the two mentioned. No big experience with either of them.

Comment: @MadPhysicist did I already tell you about [Snooze](https://github.com/joaotavora/snooze) ? Just updated my answer. In my little experience it was easier and more consistant than caveman or ningle.

Comment: No, I have never heard of Snooze until now. Will check it out!